# convert date to year-month-day using lubridate and pipes

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to turn a date in "day/month/year" to "year/month/day" using lubridate and pipes but I'm having problems. Also, the first row of 'public_release' has day and month switched. The first three rows of both `bwg_release` and `public_release` should reflect a January 6 date.
E.g.

```
    datasets %>%
+   select(bwg_release, public_release)
  bwg_release public_release
1  06/01/2016     01/06/2018
2  06/01/2016     06/01/2018
3  06/01/2016     06/01/2018
4  17/04/2016     17/04/2016
```

Current output:

```
datasets %>% 
+   mutate(bwg_release_new_date = format(dmy(bwg_release),"%Y/%m/%d")) %>%
+   mutate(public_release_new_date = format(dmy(public_release),"%Y/%m/%d")) %>%
+   select(bwg_release_new_date,public_release_new_date)
  bwg_release_new_date public_release_new_date
1           2016/01/06              2018/06/01
2           2016/01/06              2018/01/06
3           2016/01/06              2018/01/06
4           2016/04/17              2016/04/17
```

Desired output:

```
bwg_release_new_date public_release_new_date
1           2016/01/06              2018/01/06
2           2016/01/06              2018/01/06
3           2016/01/06              2018/01/06
4           2016/04/17              2016/04/17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the recommendation is to use the base `format` function. Just read the date with `dmy()` and then define your format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
datasets %>% 
  mutate(output = format(dmy(bwg_release), format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
  bwg_release     output
1  06/01/2016 2016/01/06
2  06/01/2016 2016/01/06
3  06/01/2016 2016/01/06
4  17/04/2016 2016/04/17
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do it if the date formats are mixed up? For example, if the first row the month and day are switched e.g. 01/06/2016 but then the second and third row is 06/01/2016

Comment: How would you know which is the truth? It's obvious when the day is greater than 12, but otherwise, there's no way to know without more information.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on the logic. Maybe you could edit your question with more examples?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness Using regular expression although @IanCampbell (+1) solution is the way to go.

```r
datasets %>%
 mutate(bwg_release=ymd(gsub("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)","\\3/\\2/\\1",  bwg_release)))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  bwg_release
  <date>     
1 2016-01-06 
2 2016-01-06 
3 2016-01-06 
4 2016-04-17
```